# How do I configure all clients use proxy with out making changes to their configuration

Tags: dhcp, squid

I am looking to configure a content filter for my network. I have squidGuard configured and working. I would like to have all clients use it. This includes clients I have no control over (BYOD and such). How do I have all traffic go through the proxy?

Comment: The answers below explain pretty well how you can tell clients about your proxy. However, nothing forces them to listen to what you tell them, and they can still browse the unrestricted Internet. If that's not what you want you need to block egress connections on port 80 & 443 on your network's router.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use dhcp option 252 and set the URL to an automatic proxy configuration script. Or alternately you can set up a URL http://wpad/wpad.dat with the proxy settings. Or you can do both. The DNS method is generally more supported.

This is dependent on being able to set the options with the dhcp server and clients supporting the auto proxy configuration in this fashion. Windows and Mac clients should work fine. iPads reportedly work however personally don't have experience specifically in this regard and unsure about Android. The format of the PAC file is as follows

```
  function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

// If the hostname matches, send direct.
    if (dnsDomainIs(host, ".intranet.domain.com") ||
        shExpMatch(host, "(*.abcdomain.com|abcdomain.com)"))
        return "DIRECT";

// If the protocol or URL matches, send direct.
    if (url.substring(0, 4)=="ftp:" ||
        shExpMatch(url, "http://abcdomain.com/folder/*"))
        return "DIRECT";

// If the requested website is hosted within the internal network, send direct.
    if (isPlainHostName(host) ||
        shExpMatch(host, "*.local") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "172.16.0.0",  "255.240.0.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "192.168.0.0",  "255.255.0.0") ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "127.0.0.0", "255.255.255.0"))
        return "DIRECT";

// If the IP address of the local machine is within a defined
// subnet, send to a specific proxy.
    if (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "10.10.5.0", "255.255.255.0"))
        return "PROXY 1.2.3.4:8080";

// DEFAULT RULE: All other traffic, use below proxies, in fail-over order.
    return "PROXY 4.5.6.7:8080; PROXY 7.8.9.10:8080";

}
```

Check out http://findproxyforurl.com/example-pac-file/ where that example came from. Yours will probably be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your router to use your squidguard machine as a 'transparent proxy'. You did not mention what you were using for a router, but if it's supported, there is likely a tutorial on the web for configuring it to be used with a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure squid as transparent caching proxy. 
Which is actually applies a fw rule to forward all packets to squid port from web ports 80.

A sample configuration for squid.

```
httpd_accel_host virtual
httpd_accel_port 80
httpd_accel_with_proxy on
httpd_accel_uses_host_header on
acl lan src 192.168.1.1 192.168.2.0/24
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow lan
```

Iptables rules to activate.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

If you are using squid authentication, you have to sacrifice since this is an intercepting way of network communication. Source is [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html).

Comment: Note that will only work for HTTP. They can still use HTTPS for unrestricted web access. You may need to block HTTPS and tell them they have to configure the proxy in the browser manually to be able to browse HTTPS.

Comment: There is a way to also automatically filter HTTPS/SSL. It requires quite late Squid and may not work nicely with SNI (see http://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/transparently_filtering_https_centos/index.html)